# When a CronR schedule fails to complete (due to an error). Is there a way to add a retry function to the script?

Tags: cron, rstudio, scheduled-tasks

When a CronR schedule fails to complete due to an error. Is there a way to add a retry function to the script?

Currently I am using RStudio with the CronR add-in to schedule my script. The problem I have is sometimes the script fails to complete due to an error with the 'googlesheets4' package which writes data to my spreadsheet. The error I get from time to time is "Error: Expected content type 'application/json' not 'text/html".

No is there a way to setup my CronR schedule to retry if I have an error?

Script

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(googledrive)
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)
library(shinyFiles)
library(googledrive)
library(shiny)

setwd("folder location")


us.stocks <- read.csv("stocklist.CSV", header = FALSE, sep = ",")

us.stocks <- t(us.tickers)

us.stocks <- gsub(".*:", "", us.tickers)

us.stocks2 <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = us.stocks,
                                first.date = Sys.Date()-35,
                                last.date = Sys.Date(), 
                                freq.data = 'weekly',
                                how.to.aggregate = "last",
                                do.complete.data = FALSE,
                                thresh.bad.data = 0.75,
                                cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                                         'BGS_Cache') ) # cache in tempdir()


us.stocks.out2 <- as_tibble(us.stocks2$df.tickers)

library(googledrive)
library(googlesheets4)
gs4_auth(email = "@gmail.com")

sheet_write(us.stocks.out2, "google sheet http", sheet = "stocksheet")
```

Comment: share the script

Comment: script added above. After running script I receive this Error sometimes. "Auto-refreshing stale OAuth token.
Writing to "stocksheet"
Writing to sheet "stocksheet"
Error: Expected content type 'application/json' not 'text/html'.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 408 (Request Timeout)!!1</title>
  <style>...
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.